# Is it OK to write recommendation letters for two students for the same institution and how to avoid the competition?

Tags: ethics, recommendation-letter

I am a teacher in a high school for gifted students and a student (let's call him A) asks me for a recommendation letter some time ago to apply to a top-level university (say AU: Awesome University) in our country. His level is below the average but he is very motivated and worked very hard. He is also a very nice, dedicated student with a good sense of ethics. His rather low score is explained by the high standards of my school: it is highly considered at the national level and in some countries around, and senior students can validate in advance some university courses. So I am sure that A will do well at university and I really want him to enter in AU.

Recently, after I accepted writing a recommendation letter for A, a second student, B, asked me for a recommendation letter for the same university AU. B is a great student with excellent grades. She always works with passion and could be considered as a dream student. I of course would be very happy to write her a recommandation letter and I have no worries about the outcome of the application of her application to AU. But I am worried on how my recommandation letter for A will be compared to the letter for B and whether writing for B would lower A's chances to enter university.

**The shorter, the better, here are my questions**:

1. Is there any (maybe unofficial) policy about writing recommendation letters for two students for the same institution?
2. Do my worries about one of the two recommendation letters disregarded by comparison with the other one make any sense?
3. If my worries are founded, how can I avoid the competition between the two letters?

Comment: I am sorry to say that I don't see how the question -- which concerns high school and prospective undergraduate students -- could be made suitable for this site. If one tried to modify the question so as to include graduate study, the answers would probably change: in particular, it often *is* appropriate to make comparisons in the latter situation.  With apologies, I have voted to close.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about high school students.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I think the question could apply just as well to multiple college seniors applying to the same graduate school, or multiple grad students applying to the same postdoc position, with only minimal modification. I don't see how the answers would be that different. So even though this particular situation concerns high school students, I think it's general enough to be on topic here, perhaps after a small amount of editing.

Comment: @DavidZ: "I don't see how the answers would be that different." Most unis admit thousands of students per year. Most grad programs admit less than a hundred. 2) Most letters written for hs students are written by hs teachers or guidance counselors and read by admissions officers. Most letters for grad school are written by and read by profs in the same field, who know each other at least by reputation. 3) The letters of recommendation are not a very important part of most university applications (at least in the US); they are the most important part of grad school applications. And so forth...

Comment: I asked a similar question before for grad students. I think the answers are just as relevant. The link is above.